# Can i show custom content only a user group

Tags: plone, dexterity

How and is it possible to show a custom content (created with dexterity) only a user or user group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new Workflow (Probably copy an exsting Plone Workflow is easier).
2. Grand `View` permission only to one or more specific Roles, for example `Reader` and `Manager`. Also set acquire to False (checkbox)
3. Assign your new Workflow to your custom type in the `portal_workflow` tool.
4. Then create new instances of your custom contenttype.
5. Use the `@@sharing` view to add local roles to your user or user group.

By default a Plone user has the `Member` role on hole site. 
You can give now the `Reader` (Can add) role to a specific user or group on a specific context (instance of your custom type).